# Partial Search Returns no results for alphanumeric Items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, sql-server-2012

The Search feature is indexed and running very well for foundation 2013. Using continuous crawl on SQL Server 2012 Standard. 2008R2 OS x64. I am having one issue. When the users are for searching for an item with a letter + a number (e.g. PO123) and they enter 123, the search returns nothing. If they enter PO123 or even PO12 the search works. Based on the business and list items generated from a warehouse scanner, there are many items that are referenced mainly by the number and the letter in front is not often known.

What am I missing that is not allowing the partial search on number?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/232484.aspx

Comment: Use Query rules concept

Comment: is it column where these number store? if yes than coud be please check if column is index column...also try "123" and see the result?